# Is there anyway to setup a read-only in-memory replication for RavenDb?

Tags: ravendb

I have approximately 20 workers that hit my RavenDb database 100 per minute.  They hit the database for ETAGs of certain objects to see if those etags have changed.  If they ETAGs do not change, they retrieve objects from local store in JSON format. However, if ETAGs change, they retrieve objects from the RavenDB database and then cache them to local store.

My problem is, even though the call to hit RavenDB for ETAG is very efficient and quick, this call is performed 3million times per day and ETAGs change maybe 100 times per day (across all calls).  So, overall I'm doing 3M calls per day to catch those 100 updates to my objects.

Is there a way to setup in-memory RavenDb on the worker servers (read-only is fine) so that this is more efficient?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aggressive Caching to handle that, this way, RavenDB will cache the data locally, and the server will let it know when the etag has changed.

See:
http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/Csharp/client-api/how-to/setup-aggressive-caching